# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "title contains[cd] @%"' Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to create a predicate, but get an error.I get error 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "title contains[cd] @%"'  I tried like this:

```
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
NSString *predicateString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"title contains[cd] @% ",searchText];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];//error here
```

And like this

```
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title contains[cd] @%",searchText];//error here
```

Comment: what you want the output? why are u placing [] squar brackets?

Comment: your % sign is after the @ sign. it should be %@, %d ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean `%@`, not `@%`, as the format specifier for an object.